# Lambda Expression: cast parameter to base type

Tags: c#, lambda, generics

I'd like to "wrap" the getter function for a specific property that is part of a specific type.
I have an abstract class, defined like following:

```
public abstract class MyAbstractClass<T> where T : MyType
{
    // ...
}
```

Well, suppose I've a concrete class like the following one:

```
public abstract class MyConcreteClass : MyAbstractClass<MyConcreteType>
{
    // ...
}
```

And now, the helper method that should return a wrapper for the getter method:

```
private Func<MyAbstractClass<T>, Object> GetPropertyGetter(PropertyInfo property)
{
    var instanceType = Expression.Parameter(property.DeclaringType, "i");

    // Taking getter's "body".
    var getterBody = Expression.Property(instanceType, property);

    // Cast to a generic Object.
    var body = Expression.TypeAs(getterBody, typeof(Object));

    // Build the expression.
    var exp = Expression.Lambda<Func<MyAbstractClass<T>, Object>>(body, instanceType);
    return exp.Compile();
}
```

Just like expected, I get the following exception:

> ParameterExpression of type 'MyConcreteClass' cannot be used for
>   delegate parameter of type 'MyAbstractClass<MyConcreteType>'.

Is there a way to "force" this kind of casting? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is extremely confusing. Why is there an abstract class called "MyConcreteClass". "Concrete" and "abstract" are opposites; is this intended to be deliberately confusing?  Are the two "T"s the same, or are there two different declarations of T in two different classes? Why are you trying to do this strange thing in the first place?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to create a lambda expression like this:

```
Func<MyAbstractClass<T>, Object> f = i => ((MyConcreteClass)i).SomeProperty;
```

Except you want to provide which property is `SomeProperty` as a parameter. Well, if you want to build that expression programmatically, you have to do exactly the same: have expression parameter `i` (of type `MyAbstractClass<T>`), cast it to `MyConcreteClass` and  then access property `SomeProperty` of that.

```
public Func<MyAbstractClass<T>, Object> GetPropertyGetter(PropertyInfo property)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(MyAbstractClass<T>), "i");

    var cast = Expression.TypeAs(parameter, property.DeclaringType);

    var getterBody = Expression.Property(cast, property);

    var exp = Expression.Lambda<Func<MyAbstractClass<T>, Object>>(
        getterBody, parameter);

    return exp.Compile();
}
```

Having said that, I have absolutely no idea why would you want to do that, so you better be really sure this is what you want to do and that there isn't any better way of doing what you actually want to do.

Comment: +1 I was looking for a sample of `Expression.TypeAs`. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be building the instance type from the generic type?

```
var genericType = typeof(MyAbstractClass<>).MakeGenericType(property.DeclaringType);
var instanceType = Expression.Parameter(genericType , "i");
```